# SQL Insert Command with increasing integer with phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to insert data into my database but I want the data to be assigned to all numbers indicated by profile_id. My table is called "profile_meta"

So the table structure is:

profile_id | meta_key | meta_value

I want to have an SQL command that will insert the word "userclass" in the meta_key area, the word "Command" in the meta_value and the profile_id to have numbers ranging from 1 to 554.

Okay, using the SQL command, I want to add data to a table within my database. The table is "profile_meta". The structure of the table is: profile_id | meta_key | meta_value and so basically what I want to do is database for each column without having to do it 554 times for each profile_id number

Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to insert a bunch of values, you can use a loop, inside a stored procedure, and then delete the stored procedure, if you want:

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS InsertMetaValues$$
CREATE PROCEDURE InsertMetaValues()
       BEGIN
               DECLARE x  INT;
               SET x = 1;
               WHILE x  <= 554 DO
                   INSERT INTO profile_meta(profile_id,meta_key,meta_value) VALUES(x,'userclass','Command');
                   SET  x = x + 1;
               END WHILE;
       END$$
   DELIMITER ;
   CALL InsertMetaValues();
   # IF you want to delete it after it finishes:
   # DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS InsertMetaValues;
```

Comment: I get the error: Duplicate entry '1-userclass' for key 'profile_id_meta_key'

Comment: @user3135072 Please clarify what you are trying to do. Give some examples of current table values and desired table values, if possible.

Comment: Okay, using the SQL command, I want to add data to a table within my database. The table is "profile_meta". The structure of the table is: profile_id | meta_key | meta_value and so basically what I want to do is database for each column without having to do it 554 times for each profile_id number. View a screenshot here: www.startrekrisa.com/preview22.png

Answer (score 0):

use the default and auto_increment functions

```
CREATE TABLE some_Table(
    someString VARCHAR(20) DEFAULT 'Hello',
    someID INT(4) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
);
```

Since the table is existing already, use ALTER

```
ALTER TABLE some_Table ALTER COLUMN someString SET DEFAULT 'test';
```

Comment: I've already got the table created and it has data in it already. :/

Comment: You are altering the actual schema of the table. I don't think that's what the OP wants.

Comment: I may have misread OP's post.  I had taken it as "all meta_value will have this value..."

Comment: No I don't. I want to add new data to the table. I have edited the question to try and make it clearer to what I want

Comment: So what you want is probably `INSERT INTO tableName (meta_value, meta_key, profile_id) VALUES ('someValue', 'someKey', 2);`

Comment: Fantastic, that worked, but how can I add it so it will add it to all numbers between 3 and 554?

Comment: Depends on what technologies you are using, I'd probably do it in a PHP for loop.

Comment: I don't know what you mean. Sorry

Comment: Well, how are you using this Database?  Is it for a website, or some other application?

Comment: @RichardEvans If you're just trying to insert 554 rows into the table with those values then my updated answer should work.

Comment: Nice work Alex, I hadn't considered procedure!

Comment: Thanks to all :) I've done this :)